# Can we use flyway migration only for few tables on a schema?

Tags: flyway

Can we implement flyway migration only for few tables instead of all tables on schema. Keeping in mind that the tables out of scope can be tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is the short answer.

Flyway tracks sql files (migrations) and keeps track of if they have been changed and/or applied to a given schema. It does not keep track of the objects that have been manipulated by said files. This means that flyway does not know there are objects it does not manage.

If proceeding down this path I would recommend setting flyway.cleanDisabled=true since you cannot recreate all the objects with flyway alone.

Comment: you will also need to baseline the database if the other tables exist before you run flyway migrate for the first time. I encountered this only recently where a test table existed and needed to be removed.